# display and color part of a string using span

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a text replace and highlight using javascript.

```
.replace(/sentence_old/g, '"Is \'verbexample1\' the \'verbsenseexample1\' in this sentence?"');
```

In this case, `verbexample1` and `verbsenseexample1` are going to be read in from a JSON file. The above code already successfully displays the pseudo string above. I need a way to display the sentence and highlight the "verbexample1" and "verbsenseexample1" with different colors using `<span>`. Can anyone help me with the syntax? I have tried the example below but I am getting an `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error.

```
'"Is '<span style="color: #FFFF00">'+obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.text+'</span>'+the+"'<span style="color: #FFFF00">'+obj[1].srcLanguageSentence.text+'</span>' in this sentence?"');
```

Comment: I don't see an example.

Comment: `inputString.replace(new RegExp(toReplace),replaceWith)` ?

Comment: @ps2goat I have edited and added an example of what I used.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly have you tried with using span?

you can probably do something like this:

```
.replace(/sentence_old/g, '\x22Is <span id=\x22span1\x22>\x27verbexample1\x27</span> the <span id=\x22span2\x22>\x27verbsenseexample1\x27</span> in this sentence?\x22');
```

and the following css:

```
#span1 { 
        color: red;}
#span2 {
        color: green;}
```

Comment: you have a few quotes out of place, so it throws a syntax error. try doing it the way i suggested

Comment: and use `&quot;` instead of `\'`

Comment: thank you. When I follow your suggestion, I am getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error, pointing to "Is ".

Comment: i am sorry. try the updated comment with `\x22` for `"` and `\x27` for `'`

Comment: I tried that and got a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error next to the \x22.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84515/discussion-between-alex-pavlov-and-humanitech).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really complete enough but will suggest an answer anyway.

Use  `obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.innerHTML`  not `obj[0].srcLanguageSentence.text` because I suspect you want the HTML inside the object -  but since there is no other code we cannot tell what type of object `obj` is or if you are manipulating the `DOM` as seems likely. Source for innerHTML: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

You also need to include where you declare this element, and check your javascript runs *after* the element is declared if this does not work,ie no script in `<head>`.